# How to underline existing inner html from jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to underline existing inner html but existing value is replaced

Tried but existing value is replaced with new one

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('li').click(function()
        {
            $(this).html('<strike> completed</strike');
        })
    });
</script>
<Ul>
    <li>Milan</li>
    <li>Katwal</li>
    <li>done</li>
</Ul>
```

The existing element should be underline

Comment: `<strike>` is obsolete and **not supported** in HTML5.

Comment: Also, `.html()` *replaces* content. You're looking to both append and prepend (or better yet, simply add a CSS class).

Comment: `<strike>` doesn't create an underline, it creates a strike-through.

Comment: but strike is working in html5

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for underline and then use jQuery to add that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('underline');
  })
});
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Ul>
  <li>Milan</li>
  <li>Katwal</li>
  <li>done</li>
</Ul>
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding a snippet to your answer, it makes it much easier to see that it works. I highly recommend it for simple test cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll try using snippet from next time

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, use CSS addClass property and my code will help to revert the strikthrough also not only strike through

```js
$('li').click(function()
 {
    $(this).hasClass('underlineThrough') ? $(this).removeClass('underlineThrough') : $(this).addClass('underlineThrough')
 })
```

```css
.underlineThrough{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <Ul>
    <li>Milan</li>
    <li>Katwal</li>
    <li>done</li>
</Ul>
```